# Improve profvis performance for profiling shiny app

Tags: r, performance, shiny, profiling, profvis

I have a very large and complex R Shiny app and I am trying to find bottlenecks or parts of the code to improve via the `profvis` package.
The problem is that `profvis` itself is performing very slowly (because of the processes and functions in my shiny app) so that it's lagging and almost not possible to properly view & navigate through the profile or the flame graph. 
Starting the `profvis` profile via R or via browser (firefox & chrome tested) doesn't really make a big difference here. 
I am only testing one (the main) feature/calculation in my shiny app which is initiated by one action button, thus I can't really test less features or make the profile "shorter".

Any help or tips are appreciated. Especially ways to run `profvis` faster. Another option I tried was to only wrap parts of my code inside the shiny app with `profvis`, but I didn't find a way to get this work.

Thank you!

Comment: It's a bit unusual, but have you given [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771) a try? I think it works in R.